# Median function in MDX (Pentaho Mondrian)

Tags: mdx, pentaho, median, mondrian

I am trying to implement the Median function in MDX. In particular I want to calculate the median of the measure "Amount" for every member of the dimension "Region". For this, I first wrote the following MDX query:

```
with member [measures].[X] as median([Regions].members, [measures].[Amount])
select {[Regions].members} on rows, 
       {[measures].[X]} on columns
from [product]
```

However the above query will calculate the average "Amount" for every member of "Region" and then return the median of these (average) values.

To fix the issue I rewrote the above query using a "Productid" dimension that assigns a unique id to each product of the cube:

```
with member [measures].[X] as median([productid].members, [measures].[Amount])
select {[Regions].members} on rows, 
       {[measures].[X]} on columns
from [product]
```

The above query correctly returned the median "Amount" values for every member of "Region". The problem is that the query seems to be computationally expensive and it hangs. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: 1. Median is computed over a set. In this case, would it be the set of products? 2. By elegant, did you mean a better performing MDX?

Comment: Yes it would be the set of products as defined by the product id. My main concern is speed of execution.

Comment: Is the cardinality of members of either `ProductID` dimension or 'Region' dimension a very huge number?

Comment: It's not. We are talking of a cube with a number or rows below one million. The median calculation should be as fast as the average but it is significant slower.

Comment: Interesting. So in your case, 'avg' works much faster than 'median', you say?

Comment: Create the `measures.x` as a cube member instead of a query scoped member. That should speed up things

Comment: I created it as a calculated member of the cube. Unfortunately the performance remained the same.

Comment: @denim: Mondrian seems to have performance issues with MDX aggregations, especially, if this aggregation is called for large number of cells. It is possible to improve performance by increasing `mondrian.rolap.cellBatchSize` in `mondrian.properties` file (the default value is 100000) and increasing java max memory (if you get OutOfMemory). But still, the performance will likely to remain bad.